# Why the method returns same value twice when it should return random value?

Tags: c#, arrays, random, unity-game-engine, return-value

I am making a "build a tower" game. In my game I am texturing the cube sides randomly, so every new cube has random textures on every side. The new cubes are created by the script attached to "gamemanager" empty gameobject. This gamemanager attaches the "TextureController" script to every new cube. This script is responsible for creating texture atlas and picking UVs for every side of cube. Textures are loaded and stored in "TextureContainer" script (also attached to "gamemanager") that has a method that returns random array of textures. This works great, and as planned except one thing. The first (base) cube is not created by script but set by me. It has a different script (lets call it "baseCubeTextures"), that has to get array from "gamemanager", create own textureatlas and set UVs to the sides of the cube. But the thing is that the textures of the base cube are always same as of first created cube by script. To make it a bit clearer:

GameManager has a script GameManagerScript with method `CreateNextCube()` with a line there:

```
playerCube.AddComponent<TextureController>().atlasTextures = GetComponent<TextureContainer>().getTextures(TextureSize.Ten);
```

it also has a `TextureContainer` script atttached.

`TextureContainer` has a method that returns random array of textures:

```
public Texture2D[] getTextures(TextureSize textureSize)
{

    switch (textureSize)
    {
        case TextureSize.Ten:
            textures[0] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];
            textures[2] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];
            textures[4] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];
            textures[5] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];

            break;
        case TextureSize.Eight:
            break;
        case TextureSize.Six:
            break;
        case TextureSize.Four:
            break;
        case TextureSize.Two:
            break;
        case TextureSize.One:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    textures[1] = topBottomtextures[Random.Range(0, topBottomtextures.Length)];
    textures[3] = topBottomtextures[Random.Range(0, topBottomtextures.Length)];

    return textures;
}
```

THe base cube has a script that more or less looks like this:

```
public GameObject gameController;
private Texture2D[] atlasTextures = new Texture2D[7];
private Texture2D atlas;

Mesh mesh;
Vector2[] originalUVs;
private Rect[] atlasUVs;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    atlasTextures = gameController.GetComponent<TextureContainer>().getTextures(TextureSize.Ten);
// code for setting UVs
}
```

So why do I have same textures from getTextures() method? Is it because I call this method almost at the same time (method is called in Start() of both scripts)? I read that it might happen with random number generators. Can it be somehow avoided here?

Comment: Where do you define Random? Ordinarily, one would create a single instance (e.g. a static instance), to avoid precisely the problem you descibe (2 RNGs produce the same set of numbers because they use the same time as their seed).

Comment: @RB., [Random](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) is some Unity thing.

Comment: What's the value of textures10x6.Length? Have you tried debuggig the solution?

Comment: Random.Range returns the int from range defined in parameters. I know that single instance might help (suggested by some answers from similar posts), but I dont know if it is possible in Unity. No problem in textures10x6.Length

Comment: Does it always returns the same value? Or just sometimes? (Because in the latter case, that would be the expected behaviour.)

Comment: Always same value. Since it returns an array of 7 textures it is easy to check. But I found why it is happening: since it calls for random twice at the same time it returns the same value because it is same "tick" in game loop. By moving the basecube code to another method `setTextures()` and invoking it from start with `Invoke("setTextures", 0.05)` i get different set of textures. So this has to be the problem of random number generation at the same time.

Comment: It works fine with me, I get random values while called in same method. Was the value always 0?

Comment: No, actually I get random value, but it is same fo both getTextures() calls. I should have different set for both calls.

Comment: Weird, I dont get that either. Calling two sets of random in a row and I get different results. Could be hardware related though.

Comment: hi @ŁukaszMotyczka there **is no** "problem" with Random.Range.  You just f'ed up something simple dude.

Comment: **public Texture2D[] getTextures(TextureSize textureSize)** why oh why are you both mutating the argument, ***and returning it***?  why are you even passing in an arguement?  Just do this **public Texture2D[] textures()**  (What would "Get" mean in this situation? "Get" and "Set" are specific flags for properties? you must **not** use them to lead function names. did you mean to make it work like a property?)

Comment: I need this argument for the switch statement, what's wrong with that? Also such naming helps me with writing but I get your point - clean code FTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need the complete code to be sure but I think the problem here is that the TextureContainer script attached on your GameManagerScript always return the same array pointer "textures".

You are missing a "Texture2D[] textures = new Texture2D[]" at the begining of the function.

Comment: Mmm no, that is not that. If so, he would get A NRE and not the same value.

Comment: To my complete suprise this is actually working. I dod not instatiate textures[] here because I needed to load textures in Awake() before (earlier stage of coding) and I left it like that. Now I remade the code with your sugestion and it works perfectly. Still why it did not return different random values?

Comment: There is one thing that i didn't quite understand, was that 
> textures[0] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];
            textures[2] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];
            textures[4] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];
            textures[5] = textures10x6[Random.Range(0, textures10x6.Length)];

that had all same values? or the textures from the call to getTextures() ?

Comment: the method returned different texture[0], texture[1] and so on so generator works here properly. But when another script calls for the same method it returned same set of textures. But it happened only in the first game cycle, later on, when there is only one call to the method in game cycle everything is ok (since basecube calls for getTextures() only once in a game).

Comment: Ok i see, then I think this has to do with when Unity set its UVs in the shader. Most likely when you were setting the UVs it may look "good" in debug (by that i mean different values). But if Unity waits the end of all Starts calls to actually set the UVs, they may also all point to the same array.

Comment: it has nothing to do with shaders or UVs.  it's some simple mess-up by @ŁukaszMotyczka on this occasion.  Lukasz, the question is messy because you're simply **not showing all your code**.  You've just made some simple screwup somewhere.   It looks like you still **have not actually found the problem explicitly**.

Comment: Well there was too much code to show here, but this answer solved the problem. Originally I instantiated textures array in the `Awake()` and then loaded textures because getTextures() method had to have textures already loaded since it is called from `Start()` of other scripts. then I moved to random picking of textures and I do not load them but store as array and I fill array by dragging them in inspector. Did not realize at that point that `Awake()` is not needed at that point and still had textures[] initialized there. I still dont know why it has to be instatntiated in this method.

Comment: Also it might be a problem with multiple Random.Range() calls in same update cycle. I found discusions about that in SO.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but I decided provide my answer because there I was already working on this and the current solution cannot make the random number not **repetitive**. So you will likely have 2 sides with the-same texture.

The functions below are made with timer to stop if fails to generate the random  number within 2 seconds. You can always change that. Also Unity has a bug for their Random class that sometimes returns the-same number in function with a while loop. This bug also exist in Unity even when you use the System.Random class too.

These two functions should make the random numbers of the textures not repetitive.

```
/// FOR textures10x6
    public List<int> newRandtextures10x6List = new List<int>();
    private void newRandtextures10x6Func(int arrayAmount)
    {
        System.Random a = new System.Random();
        int MyNumber = 0;

        //Reset
        newRandtextures10x6List.Clear();

        //2 seconds Timer. If it blocks exit 2 seconds exit
        System.DateTime startTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
        System.TimeSpan exitTime = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        bool quitRand = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayAmount; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                if (System.DateTime.UtcNow - startTime > exitTime)
                {
                    quitRand = true;
                    Debug.Log("Time out Reached! ...Assigning 0 to it");
                    newRandtextures10x6List.Add(0);
                    break;
                }
                MyNumber = a.Next(0, arrayAmount);
            } while (newRandtextures10x6List.Contains(MyNumber));
            newRandtextures10x6List.Add(MyNumber);

            /* OPTIONAL. WILL QUIT THE WHOLE FUNCTION INSTEAD OF JUST THE WHILE LOOP
            if (quitRand)
            {
                break;
            }*/
        }
    }

    /// FOR topBottomtextures
    public List<int> newRandTopBottomtexturesList = new List<int>();
    private void newRandTopBottomtexturesFunc(int arrayAmount)
    {
        System.Random a = new System.Random();
        int MyNumber = 0;

        //Reset
        newRandTopBottomtexturesList.Clear();

        //2 seconds Timer. If it blocks exit 2 seconds exit
        System.DateTime startTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
        System.TimeSpan exitTime = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        bool quitRand = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayAmount; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                if (System.DateTime.UtcNow - startTime > exitTime)
                {
                    quitRand = true;
                    Debug.Log("Time out Reached! ...Assigning 0 to it");
                    newRandTopBottomtexturesList.Add(0);
                    break;
                }
                MyNumber = a.Next(0, arrayAmount);
            } while (newRandTopBottomtexturesList.Contains(MyNumber));
            newRandTopBottomtexturesList.Add(MyNumber);

            /* OPTIONAL. WILL QUIT THE WHOLE FUNCTION INSTEAD OF JUST THE WHILE LOOP
            if (quitRand)
            {
                break;
            }*/
        }
    }
```

To test the `newRandtextures10x6Func()` function you can use:

```
 newRandtextures10x6Func(6);

for (int i = 0; i < newRandtextures10x6List.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(newRandtextures10x6List[i]);
}
```

It will generate 6 different numbers and they will never be the-same.

Below is the rest of the code for your question.

```
public Texture2D[] getTextures(TextureSize textureSize)
    {

        switch (textureSize)
        {
            case TextureSize.Ten:

                //Generate the random numbers here with no repeated values
                newRandtextures10x6Func(textures10x6.Length);
                textures[0] = textures10x6[newRandtextures10x6List[0]];
                textures[2] = textures10x6[newRandtextures10x6List[2]];
                textures[4] = textures10x6[newRandtextures10x6List[4]];
                textures[5] = textures10x6[newRandtextures10x6List[5]];

                break;
            case TextureSize.Eight:
                break;
            case TextureSize.Six:
                break;
            case TextureSize.Four:
                break;
            case TextureSize.Two:
                break;
            case TextureSize.One:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //Generate the random numbers here with no repeated values
        newRandTopBottomtexturesFunc(topBottomtextures.Length);
        textures[1] = topBottomtextures[newRandTopBottomtexturesList[0]];
        textures[3] = topBottomtextures[newRandTopBottomtexturesList[1]];

        return textures;
    }
```

Comment: thanks! I'll look into that :) Since I do not mind repetition in the random generations I might not apply this, but still its very interesting :)

Comment: About System.Random() - I noticed, replaced the Random.range with System.Random instance and had same results. But it is known Unity issue as you pointed out

Comment: Ok. You don't need it if  repetition is not an issue in your game. Yes, it is a know issue. I tried to generate array of rand numbers in a while loop few years ago but they were all the-same. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't happen.Many people reported the bug but Unity couldn't fix that one.  That code I have above was the solution and hopefully, it will help others. Happy programming.

Comment: WTF dude .. I was not able to read through all the code in this QA as it is too long.  But to make "non repeating" whatever you ***just shuffle***.  that's all there is to it.  `shuffled = x.OrderBy(r=>Random.value).ToList();`

Comment: Yes Joe, I   remember your solution because I am one of the people that liked it. It is very simple and more easier to implement but the problem with that solution is that it  will crash on iOS sometimes.  This is because of the use of LINQ.  The topic is complicated to describe here, but I do not use anything that has linq or unity event. One exception is if unity event is from UI. You probably haven't had any problems or memory issues with linq on iOS but when your game start crashing for no reason, you will understand. :)

Comment: It works on Android, PC, MAC but sometimes on iOS...and `OrderBy`  use on iOS is a big no no.